# Non-nested model verification

Tags: regression, cross-validation, goodness-of-fit, nonlinear, nested-models

My questions are two fold:

1. Is there a generally accepted statistic used to compare non-nested, nonlinear models with different numbers of parameters? I'm thinking RMSE, but wondering what other options might be?
2. I have a small dataset and am hoping to classify curves from it into three different families (whose curves I know ahead of time). I am hoping to use Leave One Out cross-validation to classify each curve, but am worried that the variance of GOF statistics will be too large. What are some other options?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You might consider AIC or BIC, perhaps.

Comment: AIC and BIC are used primarily to compare non-nested models, I believe. Do you know if it's appropriate to use them for non-nested models with different variable counts? It's a slightly different setting than the usual

Comment: They're used for comparing non-nested models with different numbers of variables, yes. Indeed, I'd say that is the situation in which they're usually used - since if you had non-nested models with identical variable counts you could just compare likelihoods.